# Updating Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Error

Tags: apt, updates

When I use `sudo apt-get update`, I get an error:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
E: Malformed entry 56 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I've found the line throwing the error:

```
deb http;//archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just looking at the sources.list file, aren't there other lines (that don't give errors) you can compare this one to? Or webpage addresses? That semicolon stands out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be http: instead of http;

Comment: Ohh dear, I have been forgot about ":" Thanks Now it working correctly..